# WEIRD: Javascript string.split() and forloop split prepends mysterious comma ',' to resulting string

Tags: javascript, string

So I am messing around with JS Objects, trying stuff out. I am taking a GET request, was JSON, now object. I selec the .api path. I want to traverse the object and store it's name so I can pull more JSON for a ORM expirement. Doesn't matter really. But here is the JSON:

```
var fakeRESTResponse = function() {
  return {
    "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
    "apiVersion": "1.0.0",
    "apis": [{
      "path": "/Users"
    }, {
      "path": "/Skills"
    }, {
      "path": "/Resumes"
    }],
    "info": {}
  };
};


function createSubstr(strin, thechar) {
    var substr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < strin.length; i++) {
        var str = ' ';
        if (strin[i] === thechar) {
            console.log("found first match" + strin + ' str[i] ' + strin[i] + ' thechar ' + thechar + ' str: ' + str);
            i++;
            while (strin[i] !== thechar && strin[i] !== ',' && i < strin.length && strin[i] !== '"') {
                if (str === ' ') str = strin[i];
                else str += strin[i];
                console.log(str + " : " + strin[i]);
                i++;
            }
            substr.push(str);
            str = ' ';

        }
    }
    console.log('Return substr ' + substr);
    return substr;
}
```

That was returned from the server. After trying `.split`, as you will see below, I built a manual function and some weird stuff:

### **http://codepen.io/willbittner/pen/aObVWG**

That code pen above shows the .split('/') function returning the weird objects:

```
expected: ['Users','Skills','Resumes'] 
.split: [',Users',',Skills',',Resumes']
```

Now, if I move the function:

```
substr.push(str);
str = ' ';
```

out to the next scope, 
**

### http://codepen.io/willbittner/pen/GJROEV

**

You get both the for loop and the .split() producing that whack comma.

So I know it has something to do (likely) with the values in the loop changing before they are accessed because I am overlooking something, but I just can't figure out what causes this!!

*** Note- I don't want to fix it, so plz don't respond with a different way of doing it. I want to know why this happens. ***

To me- if there was a character APPENDED on the end, that would be more acceptable, but what bug in my code PREPENDS a string, as well as SHIFTS it! No Characters were lost! It shifted it as well I guess lol.

Comment: `split()` returns an array, which you are converting to a string(by concatenating it to another string). `String(array)` converts the array `["", "Users"]` to the string `",Users"`

Comment: @Sacho you should write it as an answer